# Removing a trailing slash in MSBuild / Convention based filename generation

Tags: msbuild, conventions, convention-over-configur, itemgroup

I'm trying to search for a set of assemblies based on the following convention within a directory:

```
{SubDirName}\{SubDirName}.dll
```

I've started by creating an MSBuild ItemGroup [by batching another ItemGroup on the .RecursiveDir portion].

```
<AllAssemblies Include="$(SourceDirectory)\**\Test.*.dll" />
<Dirs Include="@(AllAssemblies->'%(RecursiveDir)')"/>
```

Each item has a trailing slash, i.e.:

```
<Message Text="@(Dirs)"/>
```

Says:

```
SubDir1\;SubDir2\;SubDir3\
```

Now, I want to generate a set of filenames from this list.

The problem is that:

```
<AssembliesByConvention Include="@(Dirs -> '%(Identity)\%(Identity).dll')" />
```

Generates:

```
SubDir1\\SubDir1\.dll;SubDir2\\SubDir2\.dll;SubDir3\\SubDir3\.dll
```

I dont want the slashes before the period in `.dll`.

What's the cleanest way to achieve this?

I know there's a HasTrailingSlash expression operator, but there's no sign of a RemoveTrailingSlash task in the OOTB Tasks?. I'm not fussy about the MSBuild version required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MSBuild's .NET methods support in .NET 4.0 to replace the `"\."`s with "."s in the final result.

(This would at least solve my original problem)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
<AssembliesByConvention Include="@(Dirs -> '%(Identity)%(Identity).dll')" Condition="HasTrailingSlash(%(Identity))" />
<AssembliesByConvention Include="@(Dirs -> '%(Identity)\%(Identity).dll')" Condition="!HasTrailingSlash(%(Identity))" />
```

Comment: Thanks Sayed. Unfortunately, the value has a trailing slash (as it comes from RecursiveDir), and I want to embed it into a filename (I am getting double backslashes between dir bits and your remedy would cure that - but of course that's silently ignored anyway - remember this isnt for pretiness, its coz it dont work!).